# Career switch to programming

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I am working on Digital Marketing platform for 2.5 years, aged 25 and willing to jump into software development(specifically Android and has some hands on experience in Android development.)

My questions

1. Do companies look for age and kind of job that you are applying ?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @gnat I have edited my question. ok now ?

Comment: well per my reading, "What do recruiters expect" sounds pretty much like ["what skills should I learn?"](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168)

Comment: @gnat How about now ?

Comment: @gnat could you please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler).

Comment: as far as I can tell, edit in rev 2 addressed the issue referred in my prior comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22088/discussion-between-taverner-and-gnat).

Comment: @gnat I have made it far better.ok now ?

Comment: Voting to close as vague. Who's that someone? You know some Android and the most specific thing you can say is that you'll PROBABLY go into Android, and you want your questions answered on that premise?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan if it is vague how did the below person get it correct ? It is vague only to you.

Comment: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.  Depending on where you are in the world it's illegal to discriminate on age.  Most (sensible) people care about talent and potential.
2. Not really. People change careers all the time. If you switched from being a pig farmer to a app developer, it might be a little unusual - but going from one high-tech industry to another isn't strange.

The best advice I can give you is to start a portfolio.  When I look at hiring developers, the first thing I want to do is play with their apps.  That speaks more to me about you than your age and background.

Comment: I have to add that while age discrimination might be illegal in some places (but not in Europe, to my knowledge...), it does not mean it doesn't happen. The companies are just more careful about it, and usually state more generic reasons for laying off older workers, or when not hiring. Most of the time they don't actually list any reason for rejecting an applicant of *any age* - just "Thank you, but unfortunately you were not chosen."

Comment: Age discrimination is illegal in the UK http://www.ageuk.org.uk/work-and-learning/discrimination-and-rights/ - and the rest of the EU http://ec.europa.eu/justice/discrimination/files/age_and_employment_en.pdf

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. In Finland, over 40-45-year-old IT professionals are almost invariably laid off and replaced with younger ones, and the companies are not hiding that. Even in government-owned companies. But then again, it isn't *truly* about age, but about salaries, which are naturally much higher for older workers: age multiplied by 100 is a good ballpark formula for average IT-salaries here. And the same happens when applying for jobs - they will take the younger one with lower salary expectation.